# I don't understand the behavior of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, scope

I'm in a formation and we're seeing pointers. We're facing a mystery :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    short *p_var = 0;
    
    if (p_var == NULL) {
        short var = 123;
        p_var = &var;
        printf("ma variable= %d \n", *p_var);
    }
    printf("ma variable= %d \n", *p_var);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the purpose of this function is to show some problems about pointers like scope or null errors. Here, the good result is `123` and `0`, shown by the `printf` but other mates have `123` and `123`. We work on the same IDE and we use the same compiler.

Do you have any idea of what happens ?

Comment: The program has undefined behavior because the variable var is not alive after the if statement. So the pointer has an invalid value after the if statement.

Comment: How would you ever get `0` and `123`? Your first output uses valid pointer that points to `123`. If you get `0` for first print, there is something wrong with the code you show. Did you mean `123` and `0` instead? The second print uses pointer to invalid address. That causes undefined behaviour and could print anything or nothing. Why would `0` be the "good" case here? It is not better or worse than any other output. While still being undefined it is way more likely that the memory holding `123` did not change since last print and that value is printed again.

Comment: Yes you're right, I made a mistake wrtigin the question, the good result is 123 and 0.

Comment: Is there a reason on the fact that the value is equal to 123 and not 0 or something else, or it's just totally random ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's random, but it could be nearly impossible to figure out the reason. Basically, the compiler assumes you will never use undefined behavior and optimizes your code based on that assumption. The results can be very unpredictable.

Comment: Can anyone write the answer as an actual answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *good behavior* for this code: the behavior of the second `printf` is **undefined**.

The pointer is set inside the `if` block to point to a variable defined in this scope, `var` which is set to `123`. The behavior of the first `printf` is fully defined and indeed prints `ma variable= 123` .

When control leaves this block, variable `var` goes out of scope and its location may be used for some other purpose... or not.

Accessing this memory via a pointer has undefined behavior. It may produce the value `123` on some machines, another value such as `0` on others and crash on more exotic architectures. The behavior can change from one compiler to another, with different compiler options, with different operating systems, or even just different times... nothing can be predicted about it, the behavior is undefined.

Your teacher is well advised introducing the concept of invalid pointers and such, but they should say that any behavior for this code is *good* or *expected*. Ask them to explain *undefined behavior* for which this piece of code and your experience is a good illustration.

Comment: @thomasrocheteau: simple curiosité, quelle formation suis-tu?

Answer (score 1):

The first printf gives the correct result because you have declared a variable var inside the if block and used a pointer variable to print its value.

The scope of this variable is inside the if block only. Outside of the for loop is an invalid pointer because pointer in c are used for storing address of a variable you haven't stored ant address outside the if block.